# Escape single quotes in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed, escaping

I have a string:

```
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql'
```

Which I need to replace with:

```
'foo' => 'bar'
```

But none of my sed commands seem to be quite right, e.g.

```
sed -i "s/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql\x27/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres\x27/g"  /path/to/file.ext
```

or

```
sed -i "s/'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql'/'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres'/g"  /path/to/file.ext
```

How can I make such a replacement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SQ=$'\x27'
sed "s/${SQ}driver${SQ} => ${SQ}Cake\\\\Database\\\\Driver\\\\Mysql${SQ}/${SQ}driver${SQ} => ${SQ}Cake\\\\Database\\\\Driver\\\\Postgres${SQ}/" file
'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Postgres'
```

You need to use `\\\\` to match `\` and to match single quote define a variable as shown above.

Comment: If you have single quotes *inside* the double-quoted string, what's the point of using a variable?  I can see why you'd need this if the character were `\x1F` or lower, but a `'` is just a `'` inside double quotes, is it not?

Comment: Sure single quote can be used inside double quotes but I just wanted to show right way to use of hex-codes as OP attempted in question. Using this way OP can use any other hex code as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using GNU sed and I'm not sure why it wouldn't be portable:

```
$ path='Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Mysql'
$ sed "s/'driver' => '${path}'/'foo' => 'bar'/" <<<"'driver' => 'Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Mysql'"
'foo' => 'bar'
```

Within double quotes, single quotes can be used literally. To make the sed line easier, I moved the path to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This works in a quick test here:

```
sed "s/'driver' => 'Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Mysql'/'driver' => 'Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Postgres'/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the backslash: `\`:

```
kent$  sed "s#'driver' => 'Cake\\\\Database\\\\Driver\\\\Mysql'#'foo' => 'bar'#"<<<"'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql'"   
'foo' => 'bar'

kent$  sed 's/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Mysql\x27/\x27foo\x27 => \x27bar\x27/'<<<"'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql'"   
'foo' => 'bar'
```

Comment: Within the sed expression, you can't use constructs like `\x27` portably.  This solution works with GNU sed, but none others that I know of (OSX, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc).  For a portable version of this, see @anubhava's answer.

Comment: @ghoti portable is not the thing to this question. OP said in his Q, he tried two sed lines, and didn't work. I copied his two lines, pointed out the problem cause, and corrected. that's it. Idon't think the answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: Hmm, you're probably right, though given that the question didn't mention a particular version of sed, and the only use of the GNU-specific notation was in something that was identified as *not working*, I think being clearer in your answer (especially for posterity) would be entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Linux person, just guessing here.

What the Perl engine processor should see:

```
s/'driver' => 'Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Mysql'/'driver' => 'Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Postgres'/g
```

Single quote to command processor:

```
sed 's/\'driver\' => \'Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Mysql\'/\'driver\' => \'Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Postgres\'/g'  /path/to/file.ext
```

Double quote to command processor:

```
sed  "s/'driver' => 'Cake\\\\Database\\\\Driver\\\\Mysql'/'driver' => 'Cake\\\\Database\\\\Driver\\\\Postgres'/g"  /path/to/file.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers given worked for me exactly as they were written, so I've used these as inspiration for testing, and found this to work for me:

```
sed -i 's/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Postgres\x27/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Mysql\x27/g'  /path/to/file.ext

sed -i 's/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Mysql\x27/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Postgres\x27/g'  /path/to/file.ext
```

or, for the foo-bar example:

```
sed -i 's/\x27driver\x27 => \x27Cake\\\Database\\\Driver\\\Mysql\x27/\x27foo\x27 => \x27barx27/g'  /path/to/file.ext
```

Thank you all, particularly @Kent and @anubhava